# Validate form inputs with conditional format checks

Tags: reactjs, validation

I have a function in React I am using to check the validation state of a form on submit.

The form contains 2 types of inputs.

`Text` and `Number`

However so I may have some control over the length of numbers in the field, the `number` input prop is set as `text` with a `maxLength` prop applied.

What I need to now do is validate that when submitting the form, the values in those inputs are indeed numbers.

My state is:

```
 state = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    accountNumber: '',
    sortCode1: '',
    sortCode2: '',
    sortCode3: ''
  }
```

I am attempting to check this using the following....

```
  checkValid = state => {
    const rgx = new RegExp(/^[0-9]{0,9}$/)
    const result = Object.keys(state).every(key => {
      if (key.match(/(firstName|lastName|)/)) {
        return !!state[key]
      }

      return rgx.test(state[key])
    })

    return result
  }
```

What I am trying to achieve is a check if on `firstName` and `lastName` to ensure there are values and then a check on all other props to ensure they are numbers and numbers only.

I cannot seem to make this work though as the form either always returns true or always returns false depending on how I amend the code.

As soon as any field is invalid, I would like to simply return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some small errors with the regex. Below code should work. =) This one will return false as soon as one field is empty or the value isn't a number on the fields where you want a number.

```
checkValid = state => {
    const rgx = new RegExp(/^[0-9]*$/)
    const result = Object.keys(state).every(key => { 
    // If field is empty return false
    if (state[key] === '') return false; 

    // If on firstName or lastName return true as we already know that the field isn’t empty
    if (key.match(/^(firstName|lastName)$/)) return true; 

    // If not firstName or lastName test the field with rgx
    return rgx.test(state[key])
    })
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to validate `firstName` and `lastName` based on their values simply being truthy and then the subsequent fields based on them being a number?

```
  checkValid = ({ firstName, lastName, ...rest }) => { 
    const result = !!firstName && !!lastName && Object.keys(rest).every(key => !isNaN(rest[key]))

    return result
  }
```

By deconstructing state you can pick off properties and perform validation separately, with less complex code.

If your only concern is that the other fields are in fact a number, `isNan` should work.